# Overwrite a class via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system, dom-manipulation

I want to overwrite some text defined by class=cc-product-infolink and it is defined by the CMS, so i have to change the text in this class via JS. It is my first time to use it, so i have wrote a little script, but it doesn't work.  Why?

I would like to change the text "inkl. MwSt, zzgl. Versandkosten " in "inkl. MwSt, Versandkosten gemäß Angaben". And the JS-Code must be work in the `head`, because there is no possibility to put it into the `body`.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="cc-product-infolink">
    <a class="cc-no-clickable-arrow" href="/j/shop/info/m/me6f40c3b0bd58b35" rel="nofollow">inkl. MwSt, zzgl. Versandkosten</a>
</div>
```

My JS-Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
var versand = document.getElementsByClassName('cc-product-infolink')[0];
versand.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent += ' gemäß Angaben';
    //]]>
    </script>
```

and it should work here: http://www.wonnemond.de/taschen/karl/#cc-m-product-8254989095
Maybe somebody can help me.

Comment: You are using "document.getElementById" while you should be using "document.getElementsByClass"

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstanding some concepts? Classes in HTML refer to CSS classes, which are used for styling up elements. Or maybe you meant you want to overwrite the contents of an element with such class?

Comment: u are right, i want to overwrite the content of an element with the CSS class cc-product-infolink

Answer (score 2):

```
var versand = document.getElementsByClassName('cc-product-infolink')[0];
versand.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].textContent += ' gemäß Angaben';
```

- Some notes:

  1. `id` and `class` are not the same. As the name implies, `getElementById` retrieves elements by their `id` attribute. Your element only has `class`, so [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) is what you need. I guess you cannot change the HTML.
  2. [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) is used to set/get
     the text content of a DOM element. Old IEs (IE8 and older) use
     `innerText` instead.
  3. `firstChild` does not work because the link is not the first child of that div. There is a text node containing a newline and some indentation before the link. Using `getElementsByTagName` you can solve this problem though.
- And a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vAbXE/).

Comment: @user3105045 Because in the HTML there is a text node before the link (the enter and the indentation tab/spaces). I will help you find a solution.

Comment: It works in the jsFiddle Demo, but it doesn't work on the site.

Comment: @user3105045 Well, it's hard to tell without seeing it. You are not putting this JS in the `head`, right?

Comment: @user3105045 Of course? Why? Normally you should put your scripts before the closing `body` tag. The problem in this case is that when your script in the head runs, the DOM is not built up yet - so any attempt to manipulate it will be a failure.

Comment: because this CMS called Jimdo, doesn't allow jS-Codes in the body, just in the head!

Comment: @user3105045 That's a problem. In that case you should put an event handler on `onload` or even better, `ondomready`, and put your code inside the handler.